# proper use of composer create-project to code and commit on project dependencies

Tags: php, git, composer-php

I have a PHP project with some 3rd party developed dependencies and some developed by myself.

Some times I happen to find a bug on one of the dependencies I maintain and want to patch it on the spot or code some extra functionality that fits the main project needs.

Right now I am coding on the module project, doing a commit and then a composer update on the main project's composer.json, whose source for the module is the *remote* repo.

I would like to be able to have the full dependency repos on the main project, or at least commit to local and get the update without pushing to remote.

I believe I can use [composer create-project](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project) for that, but the problem is I also get a lot of rubbish (the 3rd party dependency repos) that make my project huge.

Is there any way to have a composer create-project that only downloads the full repo of the dependencies I choose (those developed by myself)? Or to have the repo url point to a local git repository folder instead of a remote one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the manual](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project), `create-project`

> is the equivalent of doing a git clone/svn checkout followed by a
>   "composer install" of the vendors.

Considering that, you run

```
composer create-project --no-install
```

Then you add [local repos](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository) in `composer.json` (I'm not sure if it is documented but you can provide absolute and relative local paths as repo `url`) and do

```
composer install
```